# API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, api, android-studio, firebase-authentication

i am trying to implement authentication using email and password. the email and password authentication was working fine
but my realtime database was not working so i deleted that project from firebase and clear my Android studio by deleting json file and removing all dependencies, then i reconnect my project with firebase again and created a new firebase project, and after that this error occurred , i tried solutions like checked API key of json file and the firebase, implemented deppendencies again and all[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xDVj.jpg)

Comment: Try "Build" -> "Clean Project" and run again

Comment: Can you pls elaborate, I dont know how to do this.

Comment: if you are using Android studio on the top there is the toolbar with like File, Edit, View there is a Build click it and then click Clean Project

Comment: Ok,i got it, thank you